# Cannot connect WiFi in Ubuntu 21.04

Tags: wireless

I installed Ubuntu 21.04 system in my MacBook Air (2014 version) yesterday. However, I cannot find the place to connect wifi. There is no wifi icon in the upper right corner, and I cannot find the wifi setting either in the network setting. Any help? Thank you.

[No wifi icon in upper right corner](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nQjpz.png)
[No wifi setting in the network setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S5e8A.png)

Comment: Let's start by identifying your exact wireless device. Please open a terminal and run: `lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3` If it turns out to be a Broadcom, as I suspect, please check here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: @chili555 Thanks, that's very helpful. I have Wifi setting now, but it keeps asking for password and can't connect to wifi. My broadcom card is [14e4:43a0] (rev 03), which is absent in the Broadcam Wireless Table in the link you refered to, so I installed package for [14e4:43a0]. Is there any issue in doing so? What do I need to do further to fix this problem?

Comment: Have you tried the usual steps? https://askubuntu.com/questions/1349516/wifi-keeps-disconnecting-from-laptopt-and-pc-running-on-ubuntu-18-04-20-04/1349601#1349601

Comment: @chili555 I get stable connection to WiFi now. Thank you so much for the help!

Comment: Awesome! Glad it's working as expected.